# Polymorphic function inside a type family

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families, type-level-computation

I am trying to define a function inside a type family which is polymorphic over a phantom type of a GADT itself defined within the type family.

My type family definition is along the lines of:

```
class Channel t where
    data Elem t a :: * 
    foo :: t -> Elem t a
    bar :: Elem t a -> [a]
```

I have an instance as follows:

```
data MyChannelType = Ch

instance Channel MyChannelType where

    data Elem MyChannelType a where
        MyConstructor :: Char -> Elem MyChannelType Char

    foo _ = MyConstructor 'a'

    bar (MyConstructor c) = repeat c
```

The compiler complains that:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Char’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for foo :: MyChannelType -> Elem MyChannelType a
```

Is it possible to write this function with Rank2Types or to reformulate my data types to enable it?

---

**EDIT** : In response to the clarification Ganesh requested

I would want `foo (bar Ch) :: [Int]` to be illegal.

I have been using *exactly* the solution Ganesh suggests but I am motivated by the following more complicated example, where it falls down; given:

```
data MyOtherType = IntCh | StringCh
```

I have an instance as follows:

```
instance Channel MyOtherType where

    data Elem MyOtherType a where
        ElemInt    :: Int ->    Elem MyOtherType Int
        ElemString :: String -> Elem MyOtherType String

    foo IntCh    = ElemInt 0
    foo StringCh = ElemString "a"

    bar (ElemInt i)    = repeat i
    bar (ElemString s) = repeat s
```

Many thanks,

Michael

Comment: This is unimplementable with your current signatures. To help understand the options for reformulating it, what would you expect `bar (foo Ch) :: [Int]` to produce?

Comment: or alternatively, would you want to make it illegal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the signatures you've given, `foo` is unimplementable for `MyChannelType` because it claims to be able to produce `Elem MyChannelType a` for any `a` type.

If what you really want is that there should only be one `a` type for a given `t`, you can use a type function to express this:

```
class Channel t where
    data Elem t a :: *
    type Contents t :: *

    foo :: t -> Elem t (Contents t)
    bar :: Elem t a -> [a]
```

and then add

```
type Contents MyChannelType = Char
```

to the instance.

In response to your edit, I would break up `Channel` into two classes:

```
class Channel t where
    data Elem t a :: *
    bar :: Elem t a -> [a]

class Channel t => ChannelContents t a where
    foo :: t -> Elem t a
```

You can then define the `MyOtherType` instances with:

```
instance Channel MyOtherType where

    data Elem MyOtherType a where
        ElemInt :: Int -> Elem MyOtherType Int
        ElemString :: String -> Elem MyOtherType String

    bar (ElemInt i) = repeat i
    bar (ElemString s) = repeat s

instance ChannelContents MyOtherType Int where
    foo IntCh = ElemInt 0

instance ChannelContents MyOtherType String where
    foo StringCh = ElemString "a"
```

You'll need to enable a few extensions: `MultiParamTypeClasses`, `TypeSynonymInstances`, `FlexibleInstances` (the latter two only because of the `String` instance).

Comment: Hi Ganesh. Thank you for this - I'm slightly proud that this is exactly what I have been doing to this point! However, I have a more complex instance for which this falls down - I have added the details to the original question. I am aware that this probably needs rethinking any would appreciate any suggestions for reformulation. Regards, Michael

Answer (score 2):

As a more general alternative to Ganesh's solution, you can also constrain the `a` variable to a whole class of types (possibly just a single one):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Channel t where
    data Elem t a :: *
    type ElemConstraint t a :: Constraint
    foo :: ElemConstraint t a => t -> Elem t a
    bar :: ElemConstraint t a => Elem t a -> [a]

instance Channel MyChannelType where
    data Elem MyChannelType a where
        MyConstructor :: Char -> Elem MyChannelType Char
    type ElemConstraint t a = a ~ Char
    foo _ = MyConstructor 'a'
    bar (MyConstructor c) = repeat c


class OtherType_Class c where
  mkOtherTypeElem :: c -> Elem MyOtherType c
  evOtherTypeElem :: Elem MyOtherType c -> c

instance OtherType_Class Int where
  mkOtherTypeElem = ElemInt
  evOtherTypeElem (ElemInt i) = i
instance OtherType_Class String where
  ...

instance Channel MyOtherType where
    data Elem MyOtherType a where
        ElemInt    :: Int ->    Elem MyOtherType Int
        ElemString :: String -> Elem MyOtherType String
    type ElemConstraint MyOtherType a = OtherType_Class a
```

However, I should say that this is a rather awkward thing to do for just some fixed collection of types.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't even realize this was possible to express. Is this equivalent to the second solution Ganesh proposes?

Comment: Basically equivalent, but it would look a bit different in actual code to be used. I quite like `ConstraintKinds`, they work rather nicer for a single-type constraint as in `MyChannelType` and can (but won't necessarily) give somewhat nicer signatures than with `MultiParamTypeClasses`. For cases like `MyOtherType`, Ganesh's solution is better because it doesn't require such an awkward throw-away `OtherType_Class`.